# Is there any need of using abstract static/class methods?

Tags: python, oop, interface

For example, in Python you can define abstract class with abstract methods within [abc module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) and it works well. Moreover [since version 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractclassmethod) you can mix abstractmethod decorator with staticmethod or classmethod decorator legally.

```
class IDeployer(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_host_type():
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

But ability to mix these decorators doesn't imply the need to do so.

Can I mix these decorators or it will surely point out ill-designed interface?

PS: yes, I know that Python ABC mechanism won't really oblige inheritors to define methods being static/class methods correspondingly. Even abstract method's signature can be changed by inheritors in Python.

Comment: It is an unusual design pattern, but if nothing else, it indicates to the user of your intent.